# File format could not be determined using Metadata Extractor 2.4.3

Tags: c#, metadata, metadata-extractor

I'm trying to make a program that automatically copies and sorts the pictures from an SD card to an external hard drive using Metadata Extractor 2.4.3
I don't seem to find any prolem but every time I run the code, an unhandled exception prompts up.

Here's the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: MetadataExtractor.ImageProcessingException: File format could not be determined 
  at MetadataExtractor.ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(Stream stream)
  at MetadataExtractor.ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(String filePath)
  at file_sorter.File..ctor(String filepath) in 
  C:\Users\ropra\Documents\file_sorter\file_sorter\File.cs:line 27
  at file_sorter.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
  C:\Users\ropra\Documents\file_sorter\file_sorter\Program.cs:line 27
```

Here's the code:

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MetadataExtractor;

namespace file_sorter
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Define paths
        string sandisk = @"Z:/Images/RAW";
        string sd = @"Y:/DCIM/100_FUJI";

        // Count elements in sd 
        string[] photoPaths = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sd);
        Console.WriteLine("Counting elements in SD card...");

        //  Create object array
        File[] photos = new File[photoPaths.Count()];

        for (int i = 0; i < photos.Count(); i++)
        {
            photos[i] = new File(photoPaths[i]);
        }

        //  Create tree and copy files
        foreach (var item in photos)
        {
            string fileName = item.filename;
            string sourcePath = item.sourcepath;
            string targetPath = sandisk + "/" + item.year + "/" + item.month + "/" + item.day;
            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

            Console.WriteLine("Now copying: {0} into {1}", fileName, targetPath);

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);


        }
    }
}
}
```

File.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MetadataExtractor;

namespace file_sorter
{
    public class File
    {
    public string filename;
    public string path;
    public string year;
    public string month;
    public string day;
    public string sourcepath;

    public File(string filepath)
    {
        path = filepath;
        filename = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        sourcepath = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\\"));

        string rawDate = "";

        var metadata = ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata(path);

        for (int i = 0; i < metadata.Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < metadata[i].TagCount; j++)
            {
                if (metadata[i].Name == "Exif IFD0" && metadata[i].Tags[j].Name == "Date/Time")
                {
                    rawDate = metadata[i].Tags[j].Description;
                }
            }
        }

        int separator = rawDate.IndexOf(":");
        year = rawDate.Substring(0, separator);
        string sub = rawDate.Substring(separator + 1);
        separator = sub.IndexOf(":");
        month = sub.Substring(0, separator);
        sub = sub.Substring(separator + 1);
        separator = sub.IndexOf(" ");
        day = sub.Substring(0, separator);
    }

    public void ShowFormatedDate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}", path);
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0}", filename);
        Console.WriteLine("Dir: {0}", sourcepath);
        Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}", year);
        Console.WriteLine("Month: {0}", month);
        Console.WriteLine("Day: {0}", day);
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can app read files from SD?  With a Smart card there are three issues 1) Unlocking the card 2) There are lots of different type Smart Cards  3) Installing a driver for the card.The cards have different address/and data sizes 8 bit/16 bit/ 32 bit/ 64 bit.  You app has to be able to read the device you are using.  So first thing I would do is to try to unlock card with window explorer.  So see if you can read file with explorer.  If you can then you have unlocked the card.  So then try your app and see if it works.  If it does then you know the app isn't proerly unlocking card.

Comment: All drivers are up to date and card is unlocked, that's not the problem unfortunatelly...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so having given up and sorting all files manually, I came across an .xml file containing the metadata of a single .RAF file, I'm guessing my camera put it there.

This program does not handle MetadataExtractor non-supported files, hence the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ImageProcessingException: File format could not be determined

This exception means that the library didn't identify the file it was given as anything it knows how to read. For example, if you give a text file to the library, you will see this exception.

Perhaps you could catch this exception type and use a different code path for such files.